# Understanding this site and how to use it properly

Tags: support

I read some posts about the site on the meta forum and they explain how the site is not a forum or a discussion place for telling people how to practice their religion. I agree this is a good step.
I further agree that another good step was seeing the intention of the question if someone tells people how to follow islam or has bad intentions they should not be using the site.
This is why it took me a while to understand moderator goldpseudo actions for the greater good.

I would like to understand how the questions are judged and closed and how to ask and answer them properly?

Comment: You might want to check out the [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) as well as the [faq](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)

Answer (score 1):

Well all you are asking is well-explained in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) I mean retyping this or quoting from there hardly makes sense.
[image]

See for example:

- [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)
- [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Just to point out a few of the topics you've raised.
Please check the help-center and maybe consider taking the tour